# How can I show/hide content on a page without loading from another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an HTML game, and I want to load data from a div on the same page that would be clicked from a hyperlink and would replace the content on the page with new information. In a way, it would save me from creating different pages and linking them.

For example, I have a page of generic information, I want to click on a hyperlink, let's say "start", and I want the hyperlink to load content from a div on the same page without loading another HTML page. I also wanted the previous data on the page to disappear.

Methods and research I have tried:

1#. I created a div and put lorem ipsum text. In the CSS I set the display to hidden and none. I found out after searching that display:hidden still renders the text but isn't displayed on the render and display:none doesn't render it at all.

2#. This method was close but it wasn't what I was after, but it was using AJAX and dynamically loading data from another page.

I did find some other methods but they weren't what I was looking for.

Also, I haven't added any JS, but I'm not sure if there is a method that is just pure CSS. But I don't mind any method.

I have done something similar for one of my projects in university, but it worked only when the user set their screen to a smaller size, so that method doesn't work here.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/gulam101/pen/poPKROq

```css
head,
body {
  background-color: #3b3d40;
  color: #fff;
}


/* Title Screen */

.title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.title,
.startscreen {
  text-align: center;
}

.startscreen {
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* Introduction */

#intro {
  /* Hides content until we call upon it */
  display: hidden;
}


/* End of Introduction */


/* Looks for the child element "a tag" within the intro class */

.startscreen>a {
  color: #FFC0CB;
}

a:hover {
  font-size: 31px;
  color: #FFB6C1;
}


/* End of Intro Screen */


/* Footer */

#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}

#footer p {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
  <div id="content-wrap">
    <h1 class="title">insert title</h1>

    <div class="startscreen">
      <p>Welcome to the {insert title}</p>
      <a href="#intro">Start Game</a>
      <br>
      <a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">Exit Game</a>
    </div>

    <div id="intro">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
        et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <p>early build</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

I feel like I'm getting closer to my problem but I feel like I am missing a piece to the puzzle, any suggestions will do!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? I've updated your [codepen](https://codepen.io/navenoc13/pen/GRmGrLO). Pressing Start will hide intro div and display new content div, while pressing exit will hide content and display intro div.

Comment: Create the page with all the `div`s present (one for each chunk of content) but hidden (`display: none`). When the page loads, unhide (`display: block`) the default div. When something is clicked, hide all the divs, then unhide the one the was selected.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. The first person made it simple to understand using JS and the second person gave me an explanation. But really, thanks!